# Custom element still running after removal

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, custom-element

I have a custom element inside  tag. At some point I replace the whole  with a different content/dom but based on the dev console the custom element from the previous 'body' is still running (i.e. fetching some data). Isn't it supposed to be garbage collected(i.e. JS exec stopped) when the DOM is removed/replaced?
  Do I need to handle the removal manually(i.e. stop in-flight fetch requests etc) using disconnectedCallback ?

Code samples(reduced)

```
<body>
<x-search data-cursor="xyz"></x-search>
</body>
```

JS
    // In the real code this is another custom element that replaces the body

```
function replacePage(newBody){
    // received an event (i.e. click on a navigation link) 
    // that requires body change
    //
    document.body = newBody.body
    // At this point I was expecting SearchElem to be garbage collected
    // (existing fetch requests aborted etc)
   // but I can see in the console that it's still running 
   // (i.e. fetching some items which perhaps started based
   // on an event received before the dom was removed).
}
class SearchElem extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super(); 
        this.SearchPull = {
            "top": 200,
            "down": 200,
        };
        // Listen for various events such 'focus'
        // on each event scan the DOM(#search-results) and fetch 
        // new results or remove from existing top/tail if necessary.
        this.ListenEvents()
        let wrapper = this.querySelector("#search-results");
        this.searchPolicy = new SearchPolicy(this.SearchPull, wrapper, cursorHistory);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share code sample?

Comment: It is garbage collected if it the gc can determine that is is not used anymore, if it is still fetching data then this part of the code is clearly still referenced/registered somewhere.

Comment: @SagarBhamare I added some code though it greatly reduced.

Comment: The relevant part is most likely in `ListenEvents` or the fetching was initiated before the `replacePage`.

Comment: @t.niese there are listeners on focus or on click. On each 'focus' the element is triggering searchPolicy to check how many items we have in list and act based on that (i.e. pull more results or remove existing; it's an infinite scrolling ). None of the listeners leave the custom element boundary (i.e. they listen within this(the custom element dom, not globally) . Even so when the custom element was removed I expected whatever javascript it contained to be stopped/removed from the JS environment(i.e. listeners, in flight fetch requests)

Comment: The JavaScript code is not bound to the custom element. So if a fetch is running then that fetch is kept alive by the environment until it is finished even so it is not reference in your code anymore. So the environment holds a reference to it. If you remove the element you have to stop that request manually.

Comment: @t.niese that's disappointing... It seems I have to do  housekeeping using disconnectedCallback.